# With Ant/JUnit, what good is specifying .java files instead of .class files?

Tags: ant, junit

I'm writing a `junit` task in my Ant script, and I see that [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) says that you can specify both `.java` and `.class` files.

Why would you specify `.java` files?

The `junit` task doesn't compile the source files, so no benefit there.  And you already have to specify the class files in your classpath.  I thought maybe specifying java source files would cause my stacktrace to show line numbers, but experimentation shows that that's not happening.

So I'm stumped.  Is there any difference at all?  In fact, it seems *less* convenient.

Is there a benefit to specifying `.java` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of sources that you need to compile, you would pass that to a java task, which will compile them.  In that case it's a (small) convenience to be able to pass that list to the junit task without having to map all the .java filenames to .class filenames.

Comment: So there is no actual behavioral difference?